# Access Point/ Switch

Tags: networking, wireless-access-point

I have a router that I try to use as a switch and an access point at the same time. However, I sometimes get disconnected from Internet. If I restart the router, it works for a little while, then it gets disconnected again. Is it possible to use a router for these 2 functions at the same time?

Comment: Hello, and welcome here! Please add your router model so we can help.

Comment: Hello. TP-link TD-W8961N. Please, take into consideration this isn't the primary router. I can't find  the other's router model at the moment.

Comment: Alright. This should be possible. https://superuser.com/questions/645365/convert-wireless-adsl-modem-router-into-a-wireless-access-point-possible     Have you updated the firmware recently?

Comment: No, I haven't updated the firmare recently. I will do it and get back to you.

Comment: No improvement even after the update.

Comment: Quite sad. I feel like they are simply defective. Does the network get disconnected when it's simply a wifi access point? Or does even the LAN get disconnected?

Comment: Both. I don't know if I have made any mistakes when I changed the router settings.

Comment: I don't think they are defective. I have used two routers, and I get the same problem.

Comment: If you did a factory reset and they still don't work, then they're defective. Probably nothing can be done about them. They never had good reviews...

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to run switch, access point and router/modem role in the same device. In practice, this depends on which kind/amount of traffic the device should handle, which *Quality of Service* it should provide and the device hardware.

So, generally speaking, it seems that your device has some bug. I **strongly** suggest you to add more info (such as the device model, the traffic load, etc).

In the meantime, the only thing that I can suggest you is to check the power supply: in fact, the more the device is asked to do, the higher is the power consumption. If the power supply can provide enough power, some components might act erratically.

PS: please note that some very low cost routers (sometimes provided by ISPs) are known to have software bugs and bad performance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, I don't think it's a software problem or a bug, since I have changed both of the routers. I don't think the traffic is too high either. Let me try to explain the connection better






                                                
ISP-->Main Router----------------------------->Secondary Router(Access Pont/Switch)--------------------------->PC

Comment: The main router is plugged in a special port to the secondary router (like "WAN" ports)? I mean, the secondary router is **really** a router or you're using it only as a switch?

Comment: Only as a switch.

Comment: Have you disabled any DHCP server running in the Secondary router (if any)?

Comment: Yes. I have also given it a static IP outside of the range of primary router.

Comment: When you lose internet connectivity, can you still reach the primary router (eg. via `ping`)? And the secondary router?

Comment: I am not sure. When I try to troubleshoot via windows, I get the following message: the default gateway is not available.

Comment: Maybe you can try to look at the config panel (or, even better, the device log) of the secondary router when it happens. It should contains some clues

Comment: Will do and get back to you.

Comment: It happened again. I tried to ping both routers, no package could get sent. I used windows diagnostics, problems found were :"Ethernet doens't have a valid IP configuration" and "Default gateway is not available,"

Comment: Are you connected using Ethernet cable or Wireless? Unplugging and plugging the cable again (or connect/disconnect wifi cycle) resolve the issue?

Comment: I am connected through Ethernet cable from router 1 to router 2. If I unplug and plug again, or if I reset the router, the issue resolves for a while.